# facebook application which help to post all friends wall at a time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am very new to Facebook app development .

I am trying to develop an application which help to post all friends wall at a time. I want to fulfil this need using Facebook SDK for PHP. How to do this? I have registered my app and hosted the app with a host. Step by step instructions is appreciated.

Comment: You want to post to all of your friends or the app users?

Comment: not to all off my friends. friends of app users.

Comment: What are you describing sounds like spam. You'll get cut off real quick, you might as well not bother building it.

Comment: i have found a blog right http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/08/example-facebook-php-sdk-post-to-friends-wall/ . which describe how to post friends wall one by one .

Comment: note that posting to a friends wall is deprecated and will thankfully not work anymore after february. see roadmap: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> post all friends wall at a time.

See, you have to use **Feed** API to post , one-by-one.

1. Get all the friends of the user:

   ```
   $facebook->api('/me/friends');
   ```
2. for each friend, use **feed** to post on their wall

   ```
   $params = array(
   'access_token'  => USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
   'message'       => 'Blah Blah',
   'link'          => URL
   );        

   $facebook->api('/FRIEND_ID/feed','POST',$params);
   ```